# Can NSDockTile accept mouse events?

Tags: nsview, dock

I've tried adding standard NSResponder methods to the NSView subclass that I'm using with my app's NSDockTile, but it doesn't accept any kind of events.

Has anyone successfully done this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have updated this with a response much earlier. This is not possible under the currently released versions of Mac OS X (10.5/10.6). I compromised and now I draw a window above my app's Dock icon that contains the functions that I wanted to overlay on the Dock icon.